# Count of rows with same field with different multiple status

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table where I have department names and its risk

[image]

I want count of risk against departname. I am doing this in SQL Server.

Comment: What's your using DB,and tag it.

Comment: John woo answer is perfect for above scenario, if you have still more/dynamic Risk then go with PIVOT query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregate here:

```
SELECT DepartmentName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) High,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Medium,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Low
FROM    TableName
GROUP BY DepartmentName
```

Comment: thanks for the answer it solved my problem, i want one more help, how can we get the grand total of each row, that is  (High + Medium + Low)

Comment: @KalpeshKoli `SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
 + SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: i have one more situation in the above scenario, can we get total of vertical column, ie, total of High, medium, low at the last row..

Comment: @KalpeshKoli it would be much better if you open another question pertaining to the new scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME,RISK
  FROM YOUR_TABLE order by RISK 
)
PIVOT
(
COUNT(RISK) AS COUNT1
FOR  RISK IN ('HIGH', 'LOW', 'MEDIUM')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pivot. Suppose you have more values to the risk, you can do it dynamically with the following query

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##Table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Table

CREATE TABLE ##Table (DepartmentName NVARCHAR(100) , Risk NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO ##Table (DepartmentName , Risk)
VALUES ('BPO' , 'High'),
       ('BPO' , 'Medium'),
       ('BPO' , 'Low'),
       ('BPO' , 'High'),
       ('Domains' , 'High'),
       ('BPO' , 'High'),
       ('Bank Reconciliation' , 'High'),
       ('Godownsss' , 'High'),
       ('BPO' , 'High')

  DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(2000)= ''
  DECLARE @PvT NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
  SELECT @Cols += ',' +QUOTENAME(Risk)
  FROM ##Table 
  GROUP BY QUOTENAME(Risk)

  SET @Cols = STUFF(@Cols,1,1,'')

  SET @PvT = 'SELECT DepartmentName , ' +@Cols+'
                FROM ##Table t
                    PIVOT 
                    (
                    COUNT(Risk) FOR Risk IN ('+@Cols+')
                    ) P
                '
  EXEC sp_executesql @Pvt
```